# C++ Windows CreateChildProcess - hide/do not show the child process' console window

Tags: c++, windows, process, console

I need to create a child process as a socket listener/server for my main process and I use this call to achieve the goal:

```
bSuccess = CreateProcessA(NULL, 
            cmdLineArgs,   // command line 
            NULL,          // process security attributes 
            NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
            TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
            HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS,             // creation flags 
            NULL,          // use parent's environment 
            NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
            &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
            &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

Could anyone state what needs to be done in order for the child process' window not to show up? It's undesirable to have a visible process window each time the main, central process creates a child.

**LATER EDIT** I used:

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
if (hWnd != 0) 
{       
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE);
}
```

in the child process main function, but this isn't really the best solution as the window still shows up for a fraction of a second. If one has several child processes, each with its own window bubbling onto the screen, it is still not elegant. Are there any flags to set for the compiler to produce a "console-less" output?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag is used for just this purpose.

You can add it to the `dwCreationFlags` bitmask like so:

```
bSuccess = CreateProcessA(NULL, 
            cmdLineArgs,   // command line 
            NULL,          // process security attributes 
            NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
            TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
            HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,  // creation flags 
            NULL,          // use parent's environment 
            NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
            &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
            &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's the fastest solution (in terms of written code), but all the other answers are just as valid. +1 to everyone and thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `STARTUPINFO` structure that you provide as parameter to `CreateProcess`.

```
STARTUPINFO StartInfo= {sizeof(StartInfo)};
StartInfo.dwFlags= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartInfo.wShowWindow= SW_HIDE;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
siStartInfo.dwFlags &= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
siStartInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

should do it

Also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx