# Spawn system() window in background

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I have a C++ program that uses a few other python programs to do stuff. I'm running these in succession with system() calls.

My problem is that these system() calls open a cmd window in the *foreground*, interrupting me while my program runs and I'm doing other stuff. Is it possible instead to set it up so these cmd windows open in the *background*? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if it changes anything. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `CreateProcess`, `fork`, `exec`, etc.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think the OP is referring to the *placement* of the window, not whether the *process* runs in the foreground or background.

Comment: @Brian This is correct!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Windows CreateChildProcess - hide/do not show the child process' console window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954537/c-windows-createchildprocess-hide-do-not-show-the-child-process-console-win)

Comment: So if I get that right I should use CreateChildProcess rather than system() and I'll be able to get the behavior I want? Time to read up on that method!

Comment: You should not be using system, use the  subprocess module